# How to properly expand a bash shell variable within braces

Tags: bash

I want to do this in a bash shell:

```
n=7
cp ~/file_{1..$n}.dat .
```

What I want it to execute is `cp ~/file_{1..7}.dat .`, but I know this isn't the proper way to do it.  Can someone give me the correct format (without having to use a loop)?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Use a loop.

Comment: You can't without security risks (`eval`), that is.

Comment: ...and if the reason for not using a loop is avoiding the performance overhead of invoking `cp` more times than necessary, that's readily avoided by having your loop collect arguments in an array, and expanding that array into `cp`'s argument list. (Mind you, I mean an *actual* shell array, not a scalar variable misused as one; something like `files=( ); for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do files+=( ~/file_"$i".dat ); done; cp "${files[@]}" .`).

Comment: Maybe something like `cp $(seq -f '~/file_%g.dat' ${n}) .`?

Comment: `cp ~/file_[1-7].dat .`

Comment: @WalterA While I like that approach better when you have a fixed upper limit and only a single digit, the OP wanted to be able to use a variable for some reason, which is the reason for the more convoluted suggestion using `seq` that I made...